# SQL JSON PATH How to access a json array by index after extracting from a larger json set

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

Probably a poor title. apologies. I'm working with a large set of json data with nested arrays that are often without a name. I'm trying to extract part of this data  and then just access it by array offset.

Example that returns the array data as rows

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  
N'[  
       { "id" : 2,"info": { "name": "John", "surname": "Smith" }, "age": 25 },  
       { "id" : 5,"info": { "name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith", "skills": [["SQL", "C#", "Azure"],["ABC","DEF","BLASH"]] }, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00" }  
 ]'  

SELECT  arr 
FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
  WITH (id int 'strict $.id',  
        firstName nvarchar(50) '$.info.name', lastName nvarchar(50) '$.info.surname',  
        age int, dateOfBirth datetime2 '$.dob',
    skillarr nvarchar(max) '$.info.skills' as json) 

    cross apply openjson( skillarr ) with ( arr nvarchar(MAX) '$' AS JSON )
```

this will return 
["SQL", "C#", "Azure"]
["ABC","DEF","BLASH"]

but I would then like to return only the first elements of each array subset. i.e 
"SQL"
"ABC"

I have tried a second cross apply but cannot figure out the path convention

cross apply openjson (arr ) with (firstskill nvarchar(10) '$.[0]')

is not valid. Anyone know how I just access by index on unnamed data?

Thanks

Comment: Hi i think this post and example can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54233113/9940803

Comment: Thanks. The issue for me seems to be that my array data does not have a name : value structure, but just value. In the example you pointed out all the elements have the full name : value paring and are accessed as such from the json path. In the linked example I could do $.attributes[0]' and access the first array element by name, In my case I dont have the name part.

Comment: the answer respond to what you're looking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i think this query can respond :

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  
N'[  
       { "id" : 2,"info": { "name": "John", "surname": "Smith" }, "age": 25 },  
       { "id" : 5,"info": { "name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith", "skills": [["SQL", "C#", "Azure"],["ABC","DEF","BLASH"]] }, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00" }  
 ]'  

SELECT  /*id,*/ a /*,arr*/
FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
  WITH (id int 'strict $.id',  
        firstName nvarchar(50) '$.info.name', lastName nvarchar(50) '$.info.surname',  
        age int, dateOfBirth datetime2 '$.dob',
    skillarr nvarchar(max) '$.info.skills' as json) 

    cross apply openjson( skillarr ) with ( arr nvarchar(MAX) '$' AS JSON)
    cross apply openjson( arr ) with (a nvarchar(MAX) '$')
```

Result was :

```
a
SQL
C#
Azure
ABC
DEF
BLASH
```

For get the first skil you have to see with row_number or mock id in cross apply i think it's possible way to find what you excepted.

I think this query can be work :

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  
N'[  
       { "id" : 2,"info": { "name": "John", "surname": "Smith" }, "age": 25 },  
       { "id" : 5,"info": { "name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith", "skills": [["SQL", "C#", "Azure"],["ABC","DEF","BLASH"]] }, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00" }  
 ]'  

SELECT SUBJSONPARSER.First_Skill 
FROM (
    SELECT  /*id,*/ a as 'First_Skill' /*,arr*/, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by arr ORDER BY arr) AS 'Row_Number'
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
      WITH (id int 'strict $.id',  
            firstName nvarchar(50) '$.info.name', lastName nvarchar(50) '$.info.surname',  
            age int, dateOfBirth datetime2 '$.dob',
        skillarr nvarchar(max) '$.info.skills' as json) 
        cross apply openjson( skillarr ) with ( arr nvarchar(MAX) '$' AS JSON)
        cross apply openjson(arr) with (a nvarchar(MAX) '$') ) SUBJSONPARSER
WHERE SUBJSONPARSER.Row_Number = 1
```

And result :

```
First_Skill
ABC
SQL
```

Comment: Thanks Pascal, thats what I was trying to accomplish!!

Comment: Note that SQL Server now supports '$.sql:identity()' so row number is no longer required.  See OpenJson docs.